# How to feed new columns every time in a loop to a spark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

I have a task of reading each columns of Cassandra table into a dataframe to perform some operations. Here I want to feed the data like if 5 columns are there in a table I want:-

1. first column in the first iteration
2. first and second column in the second iteration to the same dataframe
   and likewise.

I need a generic code. Has anyone tried similar to this? Please help me out with an example.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    df2 = df2.append(df.iloc[:,0:i+1],sort = True)
```

Since, the same column name is getting repeated, obviously df will not have same column name twice and hence it will keep on adding rows

Comment: This method is also working.. but can only be run in IDE or notebooks.
I was working in REPL. Thank you Rahul for the quick response.

Comment: @Deepak: So, does it worked or not ? If not, let me know

Comment: Rahul, I have posted an answer.. Please let me know where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the names from dataframe's schema and then access that particular column and use it the way you want to.

```
names = df.schema.names
columns = []
for name in names:
      columns.append(name)
      //df[columns]  use it the way you want
```

Comment: Hi actually I also need the data along with the column.. Don't mind.. I'm a noob

Comment: see df[name] will give you just the current column (along with data) and df[columns] will give you all columns added in 'columns' list. So when you assign colList = df[name] it will give you a new dataframe 'colList' with just that column and similarly with 'columns' list.